# Join Tables and Select as List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, linq

with one having a reference to the other in a one-to-many relationship

Here's a simplified version of the two tables (don't know how to format the tables to look pretty sorry...):

Table A: 
Id

Table B: TableAId(FK), Key, Value

When I retrieve the values using a LINQ join I need the values in the referenced table transformed into a list of keyvaluepairs.
So the example answer I'm looking for is:

```
{
   Id : 1, 
   Data: 
   [
      {
         key : key1, 
         value : valu1
      },
      {
         key : key2, 
         value : value2
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's what my current LINQ looks like...

```
from a in _context.A
  join b in _context.B
  on a.Id equals b.AId
select new {
  Id = a.Id,
  Data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>()
          .Select(b => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(b.Key, b.Value))
          .ToList()
}
```

Hope my question/example makes sense but please let me know if there's any clarification required!

UPDATE: Per the comment I tried changing the LINQ to:

```
from a in _context.A
select new {
   Id = a.Id,
   Data = (from b in _context.B
          where b.AId = a.Id
          select new{
             b.Key,
             b.Value
          }).AsEnumerable()
          .Select(b => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(b.Key, b.Value))
          .ToList()
}
```

But it popped a exception

Comment: You'll need to remove `new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>()`... You're calling `Select` on that newly constructed, *empty* list. I don't have time to look at the rest, but that's going to be part of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are lacked of grouping data after joining 2 tables.

```
from grp in (from a in listA
            join b in listB
            on a.Id equals b.TableAId
            select new { a.Id, b.Key, b.Value })
group grp by grp.Id into i
select new
{
    Id = i,
    Data = (from x in i select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList()
};
```

Linq Lambda version

```
listA.Join(listB,
           a => a.Id,
           b => b.TableAId,
           (objectA, objectB) => new { objectA.Id, objectB.Key, objectB.Value })
     .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
     .Select(group => new {
                Id = group.Key, //it's group by key (your Id, not your Key)
                Data = group.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList()
            });
```